# Entity Framework code first - development strategies

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first, entity-framework-migrations

Working on a brand new project from the ground up. That means the data model is in a constant flux, doubly so because things are, inevitably, not as well planned as they should be. Model classes are being created and changed fairly regularly.

The plan was to use the latest version of EF with all the neat code-first stuff in it. But we're constantly tripping over the limitations the framework has in terms of adding or updating tables. The initialization options seem to allow only the complete deletion and re-creation of the database, which isn't really ideal.

I've had a look at the migrations. But this seems a sledgehammer to crack a nut: we don't need to detail every single small change and update with a new migration scaffold.

Are there some better strategies to deal with this? For instance, I started writing some unit tests to pre-populate one of the contexts with some test data, but because this causes the whole Db to drop and re-create, it causes problems with all the other contexts. Or perhaps making use of a custom initialiser to seed the data for us? How can we easily exclude these in production code?

We're also wondering about perhaps abandoning code-first and going back to EDMX diagrams. At least that way changes result in updated SQL commands which can be run directly against the database.

Any suggestions gratefully received.

Comment: you can migrate a Db without dropping.   And if the model is in Flux... a reseed early seems fair to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, imho, that:

- as the database schema must at least match your model you should/must detail every single change, and code first migration allows that and trace the changes over time
- code first migration also allows to migrate the database schema for you
- code first migration also allows you to produce sql that allows you to migrate the schema

For these reasons code first is as good (if not better) as the edmx approach

Please take few minutes to implement http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx

One other point, always imho and in a perfect world, if you unit test the business of you model you should not need the DAL, use generic collection. Be aware of different comportement of linq to object vs linq to entities, for example concerning the case sensitivity.